# Which would keep you cooler? A black canopy tent or a white canopy tent?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation

I was outside recently at a function and they had two colours of canopy tent set up: black ones and white ones. I was wondering which one would be cooler to sit under. The white one would reflect the light better, but it's brighter so presumably a lot of infrared ends up inside the tent. The black one absorbs most of the light, including heat, and that heat has to go somewhere.

[image][image]

So I can't work out the physics of which one would reflect/radiate more heat inwards compared to outwards.

There are similar questions asked about umbrellas that are black on top and silver underneath, but these canopies are the same colour inside as out. Also, the light one is white, not reflective silver.

Comment: There are related questions under [umbrella](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=umbrella).

Comment: I think the best would be indeed a white upper part and a black "ceiling".